# Regex pattern to strip off certain lines

Tags: regex

im handling emails through email handler , i need to strip off 2 things in each email Incoming

1. stripping off any words start with `BF00`  usually it will be one word
2. strip off few lines at body message , 
   lines start with `this email including` and end  `Thanks for you cooprate` between these need to bed stripped off

I used

```
\n this email including \n.*
```

and

```
^\w+
```

did not help

any tips

Comment: What language are you working in? Please show the code you tried, not just the regexp.

Comment: java script , code is build  in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below pattern to match the strings you want to remove.

```
\bBF00\S*|(?:this\s*email\s*including).*?(?:Thanks\s*for\s*you\s*cooprate)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qJ9cY9/4)